not able to create target groups in 2 seperate vpcs in AWS console for AWS networking and load balancing assugnment. suggest
Not able to create target groups in 2 seperate vpc in AWS console. tried creating a ALB and not able top attach target groups in seperate vpc, not able to fetch create target group in vpc.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/8EdDw4TK.png) suggest me a solution to implement.

I don't think this is possible. How would you want the traffic to go from the Load Balancer in VPC-A to the instances in VPC-B? Are the two VPCs peered together? Or would you want it to go to the instances via their Public IP addresses?
